# Is it possible to print a spinning cursor in a terminal using bash scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have seen solutions which use `c`,`python`,`ruby` but bash. The closest possible design I found was using this ruby console solution

```
10.times {
  print "/"
  sleep(0.1)
  print "\b"
  print "-"
  sleep(0.1)
  print "\b"
  print "\\"
  sleep(0.1)
  print "\b"
  print "|"
  sleep(0.1)
  print "\b"
}
```

I want an effect something simillar to that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spinners are nice, but if you really want a controllable progress meter that is aware of the IO you're dealing with, take a look at [pv](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml).

Here's a quick-and-dirty spinner. (Many nonstandard implementations of `sleep` will let you sleep for fractions of a second.)

## Bash

```bash
spin() {
   local -a marks=( '/' '-' '\' '|' )
   while [[ 1 ]]; do
     printf '%s\r' "${marks[i++ % ${#marks[@]}]}"
     sleep 1
   done
 }
```

## POSIX Sh

```
spin() {
  i=0
  marks='/ - \ |'
  while true; do
    if [ $# -lt 4 ]; then
      set -- "$@" $marks
    fi
    shift $(( (i+1) % $# ))
    printf '%s\r' "$1"
    sleep 1
  done
}
```

Comment: can I increase the spinning speed of that cursor ?

Comment: @aelo, the change to make to do that should be rather obvious, no? (If you have the GNU version of `sleep`).

Comment: So what's a good way to stop it? :) (I can only think of passing the name of another function which determines if spinning should stop to this spin() function (`spin isOver` and then instead `while [[ 1 ]]` (or `while true`) do sth like `while isOver`)

Comment: @Bloke You could use `trap`, or instead of using `sleep` use `until read -t…` and set a timeout so that it keeps going until it reads something from an input stream.

Answer (score 2):

same as @kojiro but without printf

```
spin() {
    local -a marks=( '/' '-' '\' '|' );
    while [[ 1 ]]; do
      echo -ne "${marks[i++ % ${#marks[@]}]}";
      sleep 1;
      echo -ne "\b";
    done;  
}
```