# How a printed lines get updated in a Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, gnome-terminal, terminator

In the screenshot, 77.3 keeps changing. How this is achieved? Using a carriage return `\r` can only put the cursor to the start of the current line. But in this case, the cursor is on a different line. I am using Terminator on Ubuntu.

[image: docker pull]

Comment: Would this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569195/is-it-possible-to-print-a-spinning-cursor-in-a-terminal-using-bash-scripting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html

> ANSI escape sequences allow you to move the cursor around the screen at will.

Try this code in a bash file

```
echo "1"
echo "2"
echo "3"
echo "4"
echo "5"
sleep 1
echo -n "\033[3A"
echo "magic"
echo -n "\033[u"
```

The sequence `\033[3A` sets the cursor 3 lines up and the sequence `\033[u` restores its position after printing "magic".